# Mostrar Json deserializado en variable en un label en otro from

Tags: c#, json

Tengo un Json deserializado dentro de una variable "Uinfo" en una clase llamada Userinfo de la siguiente manera:

[image: Var]

y mi clase Information donde se supone deserializa la variable así:

```
public class Information
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public string activationdate { get; set; }
    public string terminationdate { get; set; }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar el valor "username" que esta en la variable "Uinfo" en un label que esta en un usercontrol diferente llamado dashboardcontrol como se muestra acá:

[image: Img]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder mostrar el username almacenado en la variable "Uinfo" dentro de la clase "Userinfo" en la label11 del "dashboardcontrol"?

Clase Userinfo:

```
public Userinfo()
    {
    }
    public static async Task Login(string Username, string Password)
    {
        string str = "https://url.com/file.php";
        string[] cID = new string[] { "act=qwjFpPXuGexZBHDJEreZrAUH&CID=", "&username=", Username, "&password=", Password };
        string str1 = string.Concat(cID);

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Proxy = null;
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string str2 = webClient.UploadString(str, str1).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Trim();
            
            List<Information> Uinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]